# Cookies with redirect not working on Laravel Forge

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, nginx, laravel-forge

I'm auth'ing using Linkedin and setting a cookie to capture user information. On Homestead (localhost), my cookies work fine and the redirect to signup (see below) works as expected. However, on my live site the redirect gives a 502 Nginx error.

Here's the two things I've tried, neither of which work:

1.

```
return redirect('/signup')->withCookie('linkedin_user', $li_user);
```

2.

```
\Cookie::queue('linkedin_user', $li_user);
return redirect('/signup');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get cookies to work so I ended up using `Session` instead. An easy swap with no hassles.

```
\Session::put('linkedin_user', $li_user);
return redirect('/signup');
```